# Form emailing with script

Tags: php, forms

I'm french (sorry for the english) and I'm looking for a solution to this problem.
I made a form witch send a mail to the adress I indicate in the contact.php file.
The problem is that the mail I receive does not contain the "emailSchool" variable.

Here are some of my files :

My html file :

```
<div id="formulaire">
<form id="myForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <label for="emailName">Nom et prénom:</label>
    <input name="emailName" type="text" id="emailName"/>
    <label for="emailFrom">Email:</label>
    <input name="emailFrom" type="text" id="emailFrom"/>
    <label for="emailSchool">Ecole :</label>
    <input name="emailSchool" type="text" id="emailSchool"/>
    <label for="emailMessage">Message: (optionnel)</label>
    <textarea name="emailMessage" cols="30" rows="9"  id="emailMessage"></textarea>
    <input style="padding-left:5px; width:80px; height:32px;"  type="image" src="images/send.png" id="submit" class="submit" alt="ENVOYER"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
</form>
```

My script :

```
$("#submit").click(function(){                                     
    var hasError = false;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    var emailFromVal = $("#emailFrom").val();
    if(emailFromVal == '') {
        $("#emailFrom").addClass("error");
        hasError = true;
    } else if(!emailReg.test(emailFromVal)) {   
        $("#emailFrom").addClass("error");
        hasError = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#emailFrom").removeClass("error");
    }

    var nameVal = $("#emailName").val();
    if(nameVal == '') {
        $("#emailName").addClass("error");
        hasError = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#emailName").removeClass("error");
    }


        var schoolVal = $("#emailSchool").val();
    if(schoolVal == '') {
        $("#emailSchool").addClass("error");
        hasError = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#emailSchool").removeClass("error");
    }

    var messageVal = $("#emailMessage").val();
    if(messageVal == '') {
        $("#emailMessage").addClass("error");
        hasError = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#emailMessage").removeClass("error");
    }



    if(hasError == false) {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#myForm").fadeOut("fast", function(){
        $("#myForm").before('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading" id="loadingImage" />');
        $.post("contact.php", { emailFrom: emailFromVal, emailName: nameVal, emailSchool: schoolVal, emailMessage: messageVal },
            function(data){
                $("#loadingImage").fadeOut("fast", function() {                
                    $("#loadingImage").before('<p>Votre inscription a bien &eacute;t&eacute; pris en compte, nous vous enverrons un email pour confirmer !</p>');                                            
                });
            }
         );        
    });
}


    return false;
}
```

And my .php file :

```
<?php

$nameVal=$POST['emailName']; 
$emailFromVal=$POST['emailFrom']; 
$messageVal=$POST['emailMessage']; 
$schoolVal=$POST['emailSchool']; 

$to='mymail@gmail.com';
$sujet='Nouvel incrit JEIC CHALLENGE !'.$emailFrom;
$msg='Message :'.$emailMessage;
$mailHeader = "From = {$emailFrom}"; 
$mailBody = "Nom = {$emailName} Ecole =  {$emailSchool}";

mail($to, $sujet, $msg, $mailBody , $mailHeader);


?>
```

The problem is that I don't have the "School" field in the mail I receive.
Maybe somebody have a solution ? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining:

```
$schoolVal=$POST['emailSchool'];
```

And using in your header:

```
$emailSchool
```

Comment: I replace in my header {$emailSchool} by {$schoolVal} but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Does any of your values get to PHP? Because you are using `$POST` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: Ok ! Problem solved, it works ! 
Thanks a lot for your reactivity.
Cheers from France.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change  {$emailSchool} into {$schoolVal} ....

You mix POST names and locals...

Comment: Sorry I am really a noob. I followed your advice but nothing changes. What do you mean by mixing POST names and locals ?

heres my new code :

    `<?php

$nameVal=$POST['emailName']; 
$emailFromVal=$POST['emailFrom']; 
$messageVal=$POST['emailMessage']; 
$schoolVal=$POST['emailSchool']; 

$to='preaumathieu@gmail.com';
$sujet='Nouvel incrit JEIC CHALLENGE !'.$emailFrom;
$msg='Message :'.$emailMessage;
$mailHeader = "From = {$emailFrom}"; $mailBody = "Nom = {$emailName} Ecole = {$schoolVal}";

mail($to, $sujet, $msg, $mailBody , $mailHeader);


?>
`